# Is there a word that means "removing noise from communication"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to find a way to describe improving the [Signal to Noise ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) of a communication/message succinctly.  Using the entire phrase over and over gets clunky.

Phrases that are close, but don't have as much of a technical connotation as I would like:

1. "Tuning" as in tuning a radio
2. "Demunge," but it implies the message is scrambled, and I think it's programmer jargon anyway

Comment: If you don't get an answer that knocks your socks off, you can always define your own. In other words, have an early sentence in your paper that reads something like this: _"In this paper, **message tuning** refers to the improvement of a message's signal-to-noise ratio."_ Voilà! Now _message tuning_ means what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not specifically limited to transmitted electromagnetic or mechanical signals, you could consider the broader terms **filtering** or **refining**

One definition of *[filter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/filter?q=filtering#filter__13)* is

> A device for suppressing electrical or sound waves of frequencies not required.

*[Refine](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/refine)* can mean

> To reduce to a pure state; purify

Answer (score 3):

*Noise reduction* if it's necessary to be clear, *improving signal to noise ratio* if it's really necessary to be very clear, but *cleaning* can be fine if it's either okay that some of the audience will only have the vaguest idea that you are somehow making things "better" with no idea what that "better" means, or if the fact that you would do so by noise reduction is otherwise clear from context.

Answer (score 1):

The tool in PremierePro is called "DeNoiser", maybe you could just go for denoising.

Answer (score 1):

When people are using *signal to noise ratio* in respect to getting a message through to an audience (regardless of medium) the effect they are actually trying to achieve is:

### clarity

If you want to take it one step forward, the ultimate goal of increasing the clarity of your message is to increase its:

### impact

Answer (score 0):

I think I have heard "resolving" used in this context, for finding a signal in the noise.